# Why doesn't my router let me forward ports outside of 192.168.x.x range?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

Simple task: I want to forward port 80 on my Linksys router to a server with an IP address on the network that is NOT in the range 192.168.x.x (or whatever the default range is for the router). Unfortunately, this is not possible with the built-in router management page (i.e. the segments "192" and "168" are read-only). Why not? I feel like this should be a really simple concept, but I can't seem to find any pertinent information online. Maybe it's an obvious mistake on my part?

Note: My original guess is that this is because the router doesn't actually "know" about the other device; it only knows about the switch/other network device in front of it.

Comment: How are you trying to forward? Via the UI or using a console? Also - What is the option you're trying to use and error specifically? I agree conceptually it should work, but more info on what specifically you're running into may help debug it.

Comment: Do you actually have a device with such IP directly behind that router?

Comment: A network diagram with IPs would be helpful as well.

Comment: @Peter I am trying to forward via the standard Linksys UI (192.168.1.1). Under the Port Forwarding menu it gives a table where you can type in a port number and a target IP address. In this table, the first two segments are greyed out, meaning that I can only type in something after 192.168. There's no error: it leads me to believe that this is intentional.

Comment: If the router is on the 192.168.0.0/24 network, it's only going to port forward on the local network.  Did you create a DMZ?  Does the router have an IP on the other network?

Comment: @JimG. is right, if the router has no public IP then it's not on any public network and isn't going to be able to route outside the 192.168/16 network.

Comment: `Why doesn't my router let me forward ports outside of 192.168.x.x range?` - Because you have a consumer router, which has controls in place to prevent typical consumers from doing silly things like use NAT to redirect traffic to networks outside your control.  This could be use for lots of evil/abusive things.  Though it isn't clear what you want, it seems highly likely that you are attempting to do something the wrong way.

Comment: What address _are_ you trying to forward to?

Comment: @Peter JimG is only right if the router doesn't provide a method for adding static routes (or dynamic routes for that matter).  I have seen domestic routers that allow static routes, and yet still won't let you port forward to additional internal networks.  There is no technical reason for this, it is as Zoredache says, it is an intentional limitation by the vendor.

Comment: jtlovetteiii - can you change the network mask on the router to be 255.255.255.0?  If so you could have 192.168.1.x as the router range, and 192.168.2.x as the other internal network.